# Angular JS - This program is not running at all

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I am a beginner in Angular JS and this is the most basic program that I am stuck on. The below program I am trying to run is simply not responding. I included the angular-route.js function but I am still stuck.

```
<html data-ng-app="demoApp">
<body data-ng-controller = "SimpleController">

    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="name"/> {{name}}

    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers"> {{cust.id}} - {{cust.name}} -    {{cust.place}}</li>
    </ul>

    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-route.js"> </script>
</body>

<script>
    var demoApp = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
    demoApp.controller('SimpleController', function ($scope){
        $scope.customers=[
            {id:1, name='John Doe', place:'San Fransisco'},
            {id:2, name:'Jane Doe', place:'Seattle'},
            {id:3, name:'John Mikael', place:'Las Vegas'}
        ];
    });
</script>
```

This is the output

```
Name:   {{name}}
{{cust.id}} - {{cust.name}} - {{cust.place}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the working code...

```js
var demoApp = angular.module('myApp', []); 
demoApp.controller('myController', function ($scope){ 
  $scope.customers=[ 
    {
      id:1, 
      name:'John Doe', 
      place:'San Fransisco'
    }, 
    {
      id:2, 
      name:'Jane Doe', 
      place:'Seattle'
    }, 
    {
      id:3, 
      name:'John Mikael', 
      place:'Las Vegas'
    } 
  ]; 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
<label>Name:</label>
<input type="text" data-ng-model="name"/> {{name}}

<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers"> {{cust.id}} - {{cust.name}} -    {{cust.place}}</li>
</ul>

<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="angular-route.js"> </script>
  </div>
```

Comment: should really explain what you did differently .... statements like `this works` or `here's working code` aren't very informative. Also left out important dependency

Comment: First of all, you have declared **data-ng-app="demoApp"** in HTML and in controller you are trying to get by name **'app'** and your second mistake was `{id:1, name='John Doe', place:'San Fransisco'}` .... here it should be `{id:1, name:'John Doe', place:'San Fransisco'}`.... here i have removed dependency `ngRout` to execute code snipper because i don't have online plugin for that

Comment: what i meant was give explanation within the answer

Answer (score 2):

Your issue here is with the way you declared your module name.

```
var demoApp = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

<html data-ng-app="demoApp">
```

In this case, the `var demoApp` **is not** the name of the module, it is simply a variable that can be used elsewhere in your JavaScript.  The actual module name is `'app'`, so you should be using `<html data-ng-app="app">`.  I highly recommend making the name of the module and the variable name the same, whenever possible, to avoid this kind of confusion.

Also, as others have stated, you have a typo in your data: `{id:1, name='John Doe', place:'San Fransisco'},`  should be `name:` not `name=`.